# Find a value by the key in a List of Maps

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, iteration, cucumber-java

I have a *list* of *maps* `List<Map<String,String>> input`.

Which can be represented in the following manner:

```
[{AddressField=AddressUsageType, AddressValue=PRINCIPAL},
 {AddressField=StreetNumber, AddressValue=2020},
 {AddressField=StreetName, AddressValue=Some street}]
```

I would like to get the `AddressValue` for a particular `AddressField`.

For example, I want to get the *value* `"PRINCIPAL"` for the *key* `"AddressUsageType"`.

I have tried using *filters* and many other MAP functions, but couldn't end up with a proper solution.

This is my code snippet that gets the value of 1st key-value pair:

```
DataTable table;
List<Map<String,String>> input= table.asMaps(String.class, String.class);

    String AddressField = input.get(0).get("AddressField");
    String AddressValue = input.get(0).get("AddressValue");
    System.out.println("AddressField " +AddressField);
    System.out.println("AddressValue " +AddressValue);
```

Here is the output of the above snippet:

```
AddressField AddressUsageType
AddressValue PRINCIPAL
```

Comment: If you had multiple maps with `AddressField=AddressUsageType` in your list, would you want to print all possible values?

Comment: That could be possible in few cases too @XtremeBaumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Map<String, String> map = data.stream()
        .filter(m -> m.values().contains("AddressUsageType"))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);

if (map != null) {
    System.out.println("AddressField " + map.get("AddressField"));
    System.out.println("AddressValue " + map.get("AddressValue"));
}
```

Here's also a test main

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();

        Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("AddressField", "AddressUsageType");
        map1.put("AddressValue", "PRINCIPAL");
        data.add(map1);

        Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("AddressField", "StreetNumber");
        map2.put("AddressValue", "2020");
        data.add(map2);

        Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
        map3.put("AddressField", "StreetName");
        map3.put("AddressValue", "Some street");
        data.add(map3);

        Map<String, String> map = data.stream()
                .filter(m -> m.values().contains("AddressUsageType"))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);

        if (map != null) {
            System.out.println("AddressField " + map.get("AddressField"));
            System.out.println("AddressValue " + map.get("AddressValue"));
        }
    }
}
```

##### Output

[image]

Comment: This didn't work.. I received "null" as response

Comment: I still get null as response. The only difference I see from your code is that my data is initialized as:  List<Map<String,String>> input= table.asMaps(String.class, String.class);

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of Maps is a bit odd here because your actual key "AddressUsageType" is a value inside the map and every map is just one pair of key and value stored behind static keys. If you can not change that, you could go with something like this:

```
String key = "AddressUsageType";
String result = "";

for (Map<String,String> map : input)
{
    if (map.containsValue(key))
    {
        result = map.get("AddressValue");
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println(key + " is " + result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Filter the input to retain only maps which contain `AddressField=AddressUsageType`. Then extract the `AddressValue` entry using the `.map` function and gather them in a result list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<String, String>> input = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("AddressField", "AddressUsageType");
    map.put("AddressValue", "PRINCIPAL");
    input.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("AddressField", "StreetNumber");
    map.put("AddressValue", "2020");
    input.add(map);
    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("AddressField", "StreetName");
    map.put("AddressValue", "Some street");
    input.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("AddressField", "AddressUsageType");
    map.put("AddressValue", "NOT_PRINCIPAL");
    input.add(map);
    
    List<String> collect = input.stream().filter(e -> e.get("AddressField").equals("AddressUsageType"))
            .map(e -> e.get("AddressValue")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println(collect);
}
```

The output is

> [{AddressField=AddressUsageType, AddressValue=PRINCIPAL}, {AddressField=StreetNumber, AddressValue=2020}, {AddressField=StreetName, AddressValue=Some street}, {AddressField=AddressUsageType, AddressValue=NOT_PRINCIPAL}]

> [PRINCIPAL, NOT_PRINCIPAL]

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to get the value of AddressValue from value of
> AddressField. For eg.,
>
> I want to get the `value "PRINCIPAL"` from the `key value "AddressUsageType"`

You are misusing the `Map` here. Because every map is expected to have a limited, well-defined set of keys, each of which has a particular meaning in your domain. And every map is mean to represent a some kind of address.

It's highly advisable to group these data into a custom object as soon as it has a particular meaning in your domain model.

The advantages are:

- Ability to utilize different data types for values instead of storing them as `String`.
- You don't have to rely on string keys.
- You gain an advantage of clean self-explanatory code (in case if you would use clear and precise name).

I understand that it might the code that was developed long ago by someone else, or you might think that for now it's easier to store the data this was. But the more you're postponing the refactoring, the more expensive it becomes.

By treating the object as a collection, you might and up with deeply nested collections like map of maps or map of list of maps that will affect maintainability of code.

That how you can approach this task if you would choose to group the data into a domain class.

For sake of simplicity and conciseness, I would use Java 16 records.

```
public record UserAddress(AddressUsageType addressUsageType, int streetNumber, String streetName) {}
```

And `AddressUsageType` will be represented as `enum`. If I understood correctly there will a limited number of address type, so it's less error-prone to store this data as *enum* instead of relying on string values, and also gives few extra opportunities.

```
public enum AddressUsageType { PRINCIPAL, OTHER_TYPE }
```

And that's how you can extract a particular field from each `UserAddress` object in a list, by being able to benefit from its type instead of treating them as string:

```
public static <T> List<T> getAddressValue(List<UserAddress> addresses,
                                          Function<UserAddress, T> keyExtractor) {
    return addresses.stream()
        .map(keyExtractor)
        .toList(); // available with Java 16 onwards
}
```

The method shown above expects a *list* of addresses and a *function* which extracts a particular property from an addresses object.

`main()` - demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<UserAddress> addresses =
        List.of(new UserAddress(AddressUsageType.PRINCIPAL, 71, "greenStreet"),
                new UserAddress(AddressUsageType.PRINCIPAL, 83, "purpleStreet"),
                new UserAddress(AddressUsageType.OTHER_TYPE, 85, "pinkStreet"));
    
    List<AddressUsageType> addressUsageTypes = getAddressValue(addresses, UserAddress::addressUsageType);
    List<Integer> streetNumbers = getAddressValue(addresses, UserAddress::streetNumber);
    List<String> streetNames = getAddressValue(addresses, UserAddress::streetName);

    System.out.println("AddressUsageTypes:\n" + addressUsageTypes);
    System.out.println("StreetNumbers:\n" + streetNumbers);
    System.out.println("StreetNames:\n" + streetNames);
}
```

**Output**

```
AddressUsageTypes:
[PRINCIPAL, PRINCIPAL, OTHER_TYPE]
StreetNumbers:
[71, 83, 85]
StreetNames:
[greenStreet, purpleStreet, pinkStreet]
```

Comment: This solution is quite advanced for what I am expecting.  But it's good to learn. Thanks

Comment: @neyrah Defining classes and creating objects instead of placing the data into collections is a proper way of managing the data. Objects and classes are basic notions that you should understand  firmly. Your code would not become object-oriented automatically only because you are using object-oriented language. If the solution looks complicated for you, you can utilize a plain `class` instead of `record`. Remove *generic parameter* and *function* from the method (just make it expect an object as an argument and return a string). The **key point** is that your current approach is not correct.